# Why linq isn't grouping/counting as expected

Tags: linq

I am attempting to get the top 3 most popular products from my database. I have a table called clicks, which contains the product clicked on, as well as some other non important fields (such as IP, date etc).

I want to query the database to count the total number of rows where the product name is the same, and return the total number  as well as the product name.

My linq query isn't doing what I had hoped. My code:

```
 var results == (from r in this._dc.Clicks
                 group r by r
                 into g
                 orderby g.Count() descending
                 select new { Total = g.Count(), Productc= g.Key.Product }).Take(3).ToList();
```

The problem is, this returns results such as

```
11, Shoes
5, Shirts
4, Shirts
```

I would have expected the results to be

```
11, Shoes
9, Shirts
something else
```

Why does my Linq not show the total count?

Comment: shouldn't it be `group r by r.Product`?

Comment: if you want group by reference class it should implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grouping isn't really grouping anything. You need to come up with a key to group by, not the entity itself.  Apparently you should be grouping by `Product`.

```
var query =
    (from click in this._dc.Clicks
    group click by click.Product into g
    let count = g.Count()
    orderby count descending
    select new { Product = g.Key, Total = count }).Take(3);
```